# Do levels have members or is it just hierarchies?

Tags: ssas, mdx, hierarchy

can someone definitively tell me why

`[Dimension].[Hierarchy].[Level].&[(Unknown)]` doesn't make sense

while

`[Dimension].[Hierarchy].[Level].&[some_other_member]` does

and yet both `[Dimension].[Hierarchy].&[(Unknown)]` and `[Dimension].[Hierarchy].&[some_other_member]`

both do

To me isn't `unknown` simply the case where the data doesn't fall into a defined hierarchy member?

this area of SSAS seems a bit opaque to me.

Any link to the official definition would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each member is at one level of a hierarchy. If you have a standard attribute hierarchy, then you have two levels: The `All` level containing the `All` member and the level named like the hierarchy, which contains all the members found in the attribute column of the relational dimension table as well as the `Unknown` member. The latter is contained on that level, as it is clearly not part of the `All` level, and it is included in the sum of all members of its level to give the numbers for the `All` member.

The [official documentation of the `UnknownMember` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144853.aspx) describes what I described above and some special cases like the case that an attribute hierarchy has set the `IsAggregatable` property to false (i. e. the `All` level is missing, an the level named like the attribute is to only one, end hence the top level).

Comment: Thank you - that raises my first question. Why can I not say `[Dimension].[Hierarchy].[Level].&[(Unknown)]` and why can I say `[Dimension].[Hierarchy].&[(Unknown)]` if the Unknown is at the level and not the Hierarchy? I can see that the [All] only lives in the hierarchy.

Comment: @PreetSangha I am not sure why this is the case. Maybe a slight inconsistency of the Microsoft developers? Actually, I do not have much experience with the Unknown member, as normally I try to avoid it.